# How can I subset an R data.table to a range of columns where the boundary is the value of a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have an R data.table with a column "X", the value of which denotes the relevant columns I want to select. So if X=5, I want columns 1:5, and then I want to sum them. I can do this with dataframes and dplyr like so:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    sum = sum(c_across(1:eval(X))),
  )
```

But this is far too slow for my needs. I am trying to do it in data.table, but I cannot get data.table to evaluate the column. Here is my attempt:

```
datatable[, 1:eval(X)]
```

However, this simply grabs all columns from 1 to column "X", and not the integer X takes on for that row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(1:10, nrow=2), c(2, 4)))
names(df)[6] <- "X"
df
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 X
# 1  1  3  5  7  9 2
# 2  2  4  6  8 10 4
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sigma2 = sum(pick(starts_with("V"))[,1:X]))
# # A tibble: 2 × 7
# # Rowwise: 
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5     X sigma
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     3     5     7     9     2     4
# 2     2     4     6     8    10     4    20
```

You can use whatever "tidyselect" methods you want inside the `pick`, such as `pick(V1:V5)` (range of columns by-name) or `pick(1:5)` (column indices).

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, sigma := sum(.SD[,1:X]), by = seq_along(X), .SDcols = patterns("^V")]
df
#       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5     X sigma
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1     3     5     7     9     2     4
# 2:     2     4     6     8    10     4    20
```

Similarly, `.SDcols=` can include other options such as `.SDcols=V1:V5` and `.SDcols=1:5`.

Answer (score 2):

A couple options. `matrixStats::rowCumsums` will be faster if `max(X)` is not too big:

```
library(matrixStats)
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(matrix(sample(5, 1e7, 1), 1e6, 10))[,X := sample(10, 1e6, 1)]

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rowSums = dt[,sumX := rowSums(.SD[,1:X]), X, .SDcols = 1:max(X)],
  rowCumSums1 = dt[,sumX := rowCumsums(as.matrix(.SD))[cbind(.I, X)], .SDcols = 1:max(X)],
  rowCumSums2 = dt[,sumX := rowCumsums(as.matrix(.SD))[X*.N + .I], .SDcols = 1:max(X)],
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#>      rowSums 109.8403 120.69250 129.11719 123.74330 131.97455 194.2239   100
#>  rowCumSums1  53.8895  63.77725  74.48722  68.41530  80.25475 140.4062   100
#>  rowCumSums2  53.5295  62.88885  75.10741  68.00235  87.15860 112.1443   100

dt[]
#>          V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10  X sumX
#>       1:  1  5  3  2  2  4  5  5  2   4  5   13
#>       2:  4  2  2  1  5  2  1  1  1   4  7   17
#>       3:  2  5  1  5  4  3  3  3  5   1  3    8
#>       4:  4  3  5  2  4  5  3  1  3   5  7   26
#>       5:  5  2  3  5  4  5  5  2  1   2  5   19
#>      ---                                       
#>  999996:  5  3  3  2  2  3  3  2  2   3  4   13
#>  999997:  3  2  3  4  1  1  2  5  1   3  7   16
#>  999998:  1  2  1  1  4  4  4  4  4   4  3    4
#>  999999:  1  2  3  1  1  4  4  5  2   4 10   27
#> 1000000:  4  5  3  3  3  5  1  1  5   4  9   30
```

Answer (score 1):

Another *data.table* effort, relying on `melt`ing then summing to get the result. This should be markedly quicker than needing to subset columns each time as per the answer from @r2evans:

```
## example data:
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(1:10, nrow=2), c(2, 4)))
names(df)[6] <- "X"
setDT(df)
df <- df[rep(1:2,1e5),]
```

Melt and sum:

```
system.time({
    df[, sigma := melt(
             cbind(df, rowid=seq_len(nrow(df))),
             id.vars=c("X", "rowid")
         )[, sum(value[.I <= .I[X]]), by=rowid]$V1]
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.38    0.01    0.33
```

Row by row selection:

```
system.time(df[, sigma := sum(.SD[,1:X]), by = seq_along(X), .SDcols = patterns("^V")])
##   user  system elapsed 
##  24.64    0.61   25.18
```